# How can I list all non-standard modules used by a Python program?

Tags: python-3.x, module

As some pundits say that the Python standard library is listed in the Python core documentation for your version, it is built-in by default, you don't have to install it separately from Python itself. For example, `math` is a standard module, you needn't install it with `pip install math`.

Non-standard modules are not built-in, you have to install them before you use them in a Python program. For example, `lxml` is a non-standard module. If not installed, a "no module named `lxml`" error pops up when you `import lxml` in the Python shell.

It is time to turn to the topic now, how can I list all non-standard modules used by a Python program?

`test.py` is a Python program, it is executed with `python test.py`. How many non-standard modules are called when `python test.py` is run?

`pip freeze` shows all installed modules, but some of them are not called by `python test.py`.

Comment: Do you care only about the modules *directly* used by your program or also those used by modules used by your program?

Comment: Both of them,all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing, because I wanted to set up a conda environment for my project by a method other than trial-and-error. What I found worked was to make a bare environment with just python and pylint in it, using, e.g.,

```
conda create -n myenv python=3 pylint
```

and then from within that environment run:

```
pylint /path/to/module --disable=all --enable=import-error
```

This will nicely list, by file, all of the non-standard imports.